# numpy Broadcasting for user functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In `numpy`, if `a` is an ndarray, then, something like 
`np.sin(a)` takes `sin` of all the entries of ndarray. What if I need to define my own function (for a stupid example, `f(x) = sin(x) if x<1 else cos(x)`) with broadcasting behavior?

Comment: You may be introducing an XY problem with your "stupid" example.  Perhaps if you say what you're actually trying to do we could vectorze better?

Comment: @DanielF What is an "XY problem"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own function `f = lambda x: sin(x) if x<1 else cos(x)` and then use numpy's builtin vectorizer `f_broadcasting = np.vectorize(f)`.

This doesn't offer any speed improvements (and the additional overhead can slow down small problems), but it gives you the desired broadcasting behavior.

Comment: This answers my actual question (though the use I had in mind was something like the other answer addresses...), thanks! I was afraid of the performance problem...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(a<1,np.cos(a), np.sin(a))
```

Example:

```
a = [-1,1,2,-2]

>>> np.where(a<1,np.cos(a), np.sin(a))
array([-0.84147098,  0.84147098,  0.90929743, -0.90929743])
```

If you have more than one conditions, use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the behavior of this. If you set `a = np.array([[1, 0], [3, 4]])` and then np.where(a==0, 0, 1/a), you get a division by zero warning (the final result is correct), which makes one think that it actually does 2x the work needed. Is this correct?

Comment: Interesting to note! I guess it does perform the operation on the whole array, but only returns it where the condition is met (or not met)... I don't know the inner workings, but the function is often efficient enough for me.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, that's correct. If it matters, you can use `cond = a > 1`, `ret = np.cos(a, where=cond)`, `ret = np.sin(a, where=~cond, out=ret)`, but you might find it's slower

Comment: @Eric, thanks! I guess this is the price we pay for the "Python model" (where Python is the glue for underlying monolythic C++ engine). As for speed, since in what I am doing, at some point one computes the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the array, the slowdown is irrelevant (though amusing).

Comment: Note that CPU-level vectorization can sometimes mean it's faster to compute two contiguous blocks of memory and use `np.where` to pick between them than it is to compute half of each block.